# am i terminating my jsx in my fetch() function the right way?

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

this is the error i'm getting : " Line 10:78:  Parsing error: Unterminated JSX contents. (10:78)"
i thought it was a bracket missing but to me it looks right , im doing a project for a organisation and this is keeping me behind .

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

const UserContext = createContext();

const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const fetch = async (user_name, password) => {
    
      // Make a request to the login endpoint with the username and password
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3500/users', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ user_name, password }),
      })
      const data = await response.json();
      if (response.ok) {
        // If the login was successful, set the user in the state.
        setUser(data);
      } else {
        // If the login was unsuccessful, throw an error
        throw new Error(data.message);
       
      }
    
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, fetch }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default { UserContext, UserProvider };
```

this is the code for the login form :

```
import React from 'react';
import {useContext, useState} from 'react';
import {Formik} from 'formik';
import {UserContext} from '../../Context/UserContext';
 import {  useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const LoginForm = () => {

    const { fetch } = useContext(UserContext);

    const [user_name, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');


  

      const handleSubmit = (values, { setSubmitting}) => {
        fetch(values.user_name, values.password);
        setSubmitting(false);
        navigate('/MainGrid')
      };
    const navigate = useNavigate();
      
  
    const handleForgotClick = () => {
          navigate('/LoginMessage')
    }
  

    

  return (
    <Formik 
    initialValues={{user_name: '', password: ''}}
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
      {({values, isSubmitting, handleChange}) => (
        <section id="loginUser" className="sanctuary-auth-form">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col p-3 border rounded shadow-sm">
            <div className="sanctuary-auth-form-icon">
              <img className="img-thumbnail rounded-circle mx-auto d-block" src="assets/icons/organisations/icon_organisation_oasis.png" alt="Sancturay Guardian logo"></img>
            </div>
            <h4>Login</h4>
            <form   onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={{minWidth: '30em', maxWidth: '30em'}} >
              <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                <input 
                type="text" 
                className="form-control form-control" 
                name="user_name"
                value={user_name}
                onChange={setUsername(handleChange)}
                required></input>
                <label htmlFor="user_name" aria-label=".form-control">username</label>
              </div>
              <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                <input
                type="password" 
                className="form-control form-control" 
                name="password"
                value={password} 
                onChange={setPassword(handleChange)}
                required>
                </input>
                <label htmlFor="password" aria-label=".form-control">Password</label>
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3 text-end">
                <a className="link-danger" onClick={handleForgotClick} >Forgot login details</a>
              </div>
              <div className="d-grid text-end">              
                <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting} >Login</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      )}
    
  </Formik>
  
  )
}

export default LoginForm
```

i don't even know why the error is being throwed , some clarity on the why the error is being generated would help me for future reference

Comment: `await fetch('http://...` is calling `const fetch = async (user_name, password) =>`

Comment: Where is the error being thrown from?

Comment: fetch is an in built function to call API's, but you function name is also fetch
change function name first and check again

Comment: @Spikatrix it says its being thrown from line 10 , so that would be here ```

Comment: @ANARKID Your comment is incomplete. Please edit your question to include which line is causing the error.

Comment: my apologies : ```  // this is where the error is coming from  ->const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3500/users', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ user_name, password }),
      }) ``